Table with preset variable is slower than table with explicit number
Why it takes ages to evaluate the second table compared to the first one?
The tables are same except that first uses explicit constant 667 while the second one uses variable c=667;
$Version

c = 667;

Table[Sqrt[1 - x^2] Boole[4 < y <= 667 || 2*667 < y < 3*667 - 3] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.06, 0.06}], {x, -1, 1, .001}, {y, 667*3}]; // Timing

Table[Sqrt[1 - x^2] Boole[4 < y <= c || 2*c < y < 3 c - 3] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.06, 0.06}], {x, -1, 1, .001}, {y, c*3}]; // Timing


"13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"

{0.984375, Null}

{16.7813, Null}


Probably, because Mathematica is able to compile the first table without external calls?

Hint: Use With[{c = c},  b = Table[    Sqrt[1 - x^2] Boole[4 < y <= c || 2*c < y < 3 c - 3] +      RandomReal[{-0.06, 0.06}], {x, -1, 1, .001}, {y, c*3}]  ]; This makes the value if c a compile-time constant.

It's because the first one can be (and is) compiled, while the second one cannot be. You can turn off compiling to see that this is the reason:
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> ∞}];

c = 667;
Table[Sqrt[1 - x^2]  Boole[4 < y <= 667 || 2*667 < y < 3*667 - 3] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.06, 0.06}], {x, -1, 1, .001}, {y, 667*3}]; // Timing
(* {3.375, Null} *)
Table[Sqrt[1 - x^2]  Boole[4 < y <= c || 2*c < y < 3  c - 3] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.06, 0.06}], {x, -1, 1, .001}, {y, c*3}]; // Timing
(* {3.51563, Null} *)

And you can also turn on the messages:
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 250, 
   "CompileReportFailure" -> True}]
Table[Sqrt[1 - x^2]  Boole[4 < y <= c || 2*c < y < 3  c - 3] + 
    RandomReal[{-0.06, 0.06}], {x, -1, 1, .001}, {y, c*3}]; // Timing
(* Compile::compfail: Compilation of Table[...,{x,-1,1,0.001},{y,c 3}] failed
   because c was not a form suitable for the compiler. *)

And of course it's the c in the iteration limits of Table that is problematic, not c inside Boole. As suggested by @Henrik Schumacher, either lexically insert the value of c, or Evaluate the limits beforehand:
With[{c = c}, Table[..., {y, c*3}]]
Table[..., Evaluate@{y, c*3}]


Good to know the reason although I consider it disappointing that table's performance fails on such trivialities which could be treated automatically by default.
